# Getting a function from a list of tuples

Tags: haskell

Given a list of tuples, for example `x = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)]` I want to extract the function which maps `1 to 2, 2 to 3 and 3 to 1` (i.e. I want to construct a function from its set theoretic definition).
So far I constructed the following to define a function from a tuple

```
mfromt :: (Int,Int) -> (Int -> Int)  
mfromt (a,b) = f where  
    f x  
    | x == a = b
```

but I have no idea how to generalize this to a list of tuples, I would need some way of combining partially defined functions. But I have the strong feeling that there should be a better solution anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [lookup](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lookup) is function you need:

```hs
lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
```

But it return `Maybe b` type because corresponding pair may not be in input list.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for! I already wondered why there would be no function for such (I guess) common problem.

Answer (score 1):

We can implement this as a cascade where if a function fails, we go to the next function. So for the given list of tuples, we can implement this as:

```
f0 :: Int -> Int
f0 = error "variable out of range"

f1 :: Int -> Int
f1 x
  | x == 1 = 2
  | otherwise = f2 x


f2 :: Int -> Int
f2 x
  | x == 2 = 3
  | otherwise = f2 x


f3 :: Int -> Int
f3 x
  | x == 3 = 1
  | otherwise = f2 x
```

Now of course here we hardcode the values. We can however implement a function that makes such `f` through parameters, so:

```
genF :: Int -> Int -> (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int)
genF x y f x0
  | x0 == x = y
  | otherwise = f x
```

Finally we can make use of `foldr` (or `foldl`) to construct such function per 2-tuple in the list. This will thus look like:

```
mfromt :: [(Int, Int)] -> Int -> Int
mfromt fs = foldr (…) (error "variable out of range") fs
```

where I leave implementing `…` as an exercise. This function has as type `… :: (Int, Int) -> (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int)` and thus should use the `genF` function.